# Javascript image data to multidimensional array performance issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, multidimensional-array, getimagedata

I wrote a method for converting the canvas image data array into a multidimensional coordinate based array like such:

```
parse: function() {
    var x = y = 0;
    var step = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i <= this.imageData.length - 4; i += 4) {
        if(step == this.width) {
            ++ y;
            step = 0;
        }
        this.data[x][y] = [this.imageData[i],
                           this.imageData[i+1],
                           this.imageData[i+2],
                           this.imageData[i+3]];

        ++ x;
        ++ step;
    }
}
```

I have tested it out on a smaller scale (10x10 image), however when I move to a larger image, in my case 800x800, it completely crashes the browser(tab). I can understand why, however, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to go about this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You could do a little less math by taking advantage of the `%` (modulus) operator like this:

```
var floor = Math.floor; // store a reference to Math.floor, anything goes when you have 640,000 iterations 

parse: function(imageHeight, imageWidth) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.imageData.length; i++) {
        this.data[i % imageWidth][Math.floor(i/imageHeight)] = [this.imageData[i],
                           this.imageData[i+1],
                           this.imageData[i+2],
                           this.imageData[i+3]];

    }
}​
```

You'll have to come up with the values for `imageHeight` and `imageWidth`, of course.

Comment: I really like this solution, however I seem to be getting undefined data `console.log(this.data[0][360]);` where I would expect an array. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, this solution seems to increment the array improperly. It increments every four pixels is `this.data[0][0], this.data[4][0], this.data[8][0] etc..`

Comment: Aha, that would do it. Btw, I've updated my answer once more to squeeze that last bit of speed out of the for loop. :) Let me see if I can see what's going wrong with the iterations.

Comment: @Headspin: Ah, found it. I copied your for loop then changed the logic so that incrementing by four was no longer needed. Check the answer again.

Comment: 2 problems here. The image data array is made up of `[r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a...]` so every four makes a pixel. Also, while this gets all the x positions (`this.data[0..799]`), each x only has 40 y's (`this.data[x][0..39]`).